# is there any way to prevent opening modal with data-bs-target before validation?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5.2.3, and I want to validate values before opening a modal.

it seems data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target always opens the target modal.
and I tried to change the value in vuejs like below and it doesn't work, and I tried to look up the documentation and other posts that gives jquery as a solution and they all didn't work. how can I run a validation method and open a modal with data-bs only if the validation is passed?

template part:

```
// the button
 <button
  type="button"
  @click="validate()"
  class="submitBtn"
  :data-bs-toggle="isValidFirst ? 'modal' : ''"
  :data-bs-target="isValidFirst ? '#popup' : ''"
>
  <p>Save</p>
</button>

// the modal popup
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="popup"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="popupLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  this is modal
</div>
```

and script part:

```
validateFirstStep() {
  if(!this.userId) this.isValidFirst = false;
  if(!this.userName) this.isValidFirst = false;

  if(this.isValidFirst) {
    this.submitData();
  } 
},
```

to validate values before data-bs-toggle opens a modal,

tried to change data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target as a vue data(with colon) that changes based on the value of a boolean variable
and the validation method changes the value of the boolean variable

and the modal did not show up.

something like modal.show() also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think if you use jQuery it will help you, try removing data-bs attributes and use instead this code:

```
$("#popup").modal('show') // to show the modal
```

and if you want to hide it again use:

```
$("#popup").modal('hide')
```

and use the function when you want the modal to be opened.
hope this works for you.

Comment: interesting, doing this with jquery npm package didn't work but doing this with jquery cdn worked.